# IE9 not liking my dropdown box?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Hi i am trying to make IE9 when i press my drop-down open the selected options. It works on every other browser but IE9 when you press the custom Drop-down icon it doesnt open, yet it opens when you press the input box.

CSS code:

```
.Dropdown label:after {
  content: '>';
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: 17px;
  top: 11px;
  padding: 0 0 2px;
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; */
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.Dropdown label:before {
  content: '';
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 44px;
  height: 3.2em;
  background: #ec008c;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I don't know if this is because of my CSS?

Comment: Could you set up a working example on (for example) JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

When pointer-events is set to none, the element is never the target of mouse events. Try removing that.